# Website loads very slow in safari 6.02 on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: performance, safari, html

I am working on a website for a client and I just tested it in every browser i can think of.  It nearly every browser the website loads fine, in under 2 seconds.  But for some reason in Safari the website takes nearly 20 seconds to load.

I am testing with Safari 6.02 on OSX 10.8.2

[edit] website address removed as it was a development server please view answer for permanent links to a demo about the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only your Safari, or every Safari? (other people experience it too?)

Comment: I have tested it in Safari 6 on my iPad and it happened there.  It does not happen in Sarafi 5 in my Windows 7 machine.  It does happen in Safari 6 on another macbook pro other than mine.  It also does not happen in my iOS simulator for iPhone, but it does happen in the iOS simulator for iPad.

Comment: I have tried disabling all the javascript on the site, but it still loads very slowly, its almost as if Safari 6 doesn't like my image files.

Comment: not sure if safari does have something like the network tab in element inspector in chrome, but try to find some output like that to find out what exactly takes so long to load.. if it has problems establishing connection to the server or if it loads something in particular slowly..

Comment: Yeah, it does, it is hanging on every image it needs to load for about 3 seconds. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39497/firefox19.waterfall.png vs https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39497/safari6.waterfall.png

Comment: Also, here is a waterfall for safari4 where the problem does not occur: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39497/safari4.waterfall.png (unfortunately i cannot run safari 5 right now to test)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the css property: text-shadow that was causing all my problems.

The designer for this site had used some pink glow around some of the text so i was using rules like this in four places:

```
text-shadow: 
  0 0 10px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 20px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 30px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 40px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 70px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 80px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 100px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6), 
  0 0 150px rgba(60,3,64, 0.6);
```

Now that text shadow works fine, and looks pretty decent in almost every modern browser out there, but it really makes safari 6 chug along slowly.  In fact on the iPad it nearly crashes the browser.  And the client complained that it crashed the browser on his iMac as well (although i have not been able to replicate this behavior as i do not own an iMac).

Ok, so i built a demo, to show others what i am talking about:

http://www.waspdigital.com/demo/text-shadow-on
and
http://www.waspdigital.com/demo/text-shadow-off

Please visit both links in the latest version of safari and you will see what i am talking about.